On the set of positive values of a non negative function
Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0 , \infty)     $ be a function such that for any finite set $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ we have
$\Sigma_{x\in E} f(x)\le 1 $
Let $C_f=\{ x\in \mathbb{R} | f(x)>0\}      \subset \mathbb{R} $ . Then
(1) $C_f$ is finite.
(2) $C_f$ is bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$
(3) $C_f$ has at most one limit point
(4) $C_f$ is a countable set.
I was thinking of the result  that sum of uncountable number of positive reals is always diverging to infinity .
So if $C_f    $ is uncountable then
$\Sigma_{x\in C_f} f(x) =\infty $ for which we get a finite $E \subset C_f$ such that  $\Sigma_{x\in E}f(x) > 1 $ , a contradiction ?
There are other similar sounding questions but unsure how to use here.
I am not sure even if  the last line/conclusion is correct. Hints please .

Your conclusion is correct: $C_f$ cannot be uncountable.  On the other hand, for any sequence of distinct real numbers  $x_n$ you can define $f(x_n)$ to be some sequence of positive numbers whose sum converges, and take $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

@RobertIsrael Thank you sir..now got it

Your conclusion is correct but I think your explanation needs work.  How would you select a finite subset of $C_f$ so that the sum is greater than $1$?

@fleablood yes sir ..so if for all finite subsets of $C_f$  , the sum is lesser or equal to $1$ which proves $C_f$  must be at most countable but we assumed $C_f$ is uncountable .

".so if for all finite subsets of Cf , the sum is lesser or equal to 1 which proves Cf must be at most countable " how does that prove that?  I'm sure you are correct but I'm not following your arguments.

For any integer $n>0$ the set of $x$ such that $f(x)>\tfrac{1}{n}$ is finite. So $C_f$ is a countable union of finite sets. Using the same idea, any countable set equals $C_f$ for some $f$.
